# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'product' with no arguments not found

Tags: django

I have this error `NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'product' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['product\\/(?P<slug>[^/]+)$']` when using Django urls patterns

This is my URL patterns

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('',HomeView.as_view(),name='home'),
    path('checkout/',checkout,name='checkout'),
    path('product/<str:slug>',ItemDetailView.as_view(),name='product'),
    ]
```

This is my views.py

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
model = Item
template_name = 'product.html'
```

This is my models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
price = models.FloatField()
category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES,max_length=2)
label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES,max_length=1)
slug = models.SlugField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('core:product',kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
```

This is my base.html

```
 <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link waves-effect" href="{% url 'core:checkout' %}" target="_blank">Checkout</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link waves-effect" href="{% url 'core:product' %}" target="_blank">Product</a>
                    </li>
```

Comment: please post code in codeblocks and not as images

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is in the `base.html` you try to get the url with `{% url 'core:product' %}` but in your `urls.py` you expect the `slug` as well. You have to pass this variable. ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url))

Comment: i did as {{% url 'core:product' core.slug  %}},{{% url 'core:product' item.slug  %}} and {{% url 'core:product' slug  %}},{{% url 'core:product' Item.slug  %}}, but still faced the same issue

Comment: are the values `core.slug`, `item.slug` or `slug` defined? / is for example every time you render a view a item `core` passed in the context or a item called `item`? usually the `base.html` is the base for every page an therefore you don't have there a "detail" linked directly but the "list" of a model linked and then you wouldn't need a variable